# Upgrade without UpgradeCode with MSI

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, installshield

I have a maschine where a software is installed which was created using InstallShield and the project doesn't contain UpgradeCode. I got to know that the UpgradeCodes were never assigned. If I were to update the software without completly uninstalling manually, how can it be achieved? I am using WIXtool in VisualStudio for creating MSI which is capable of installing the desired software but isn't able to replace or upgrade old software.

I tried to create a minor patch for which I though I will use the old InstallShield project and add UpgradeCode to it and create a new setup. But in my InstallShield, there is no option to put UpgradeCode. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ehKn.png)

Comment: Seems you're using very old version. Option is generally available in media > Upgrades. Otherwise, Try Direct Editor in Installshield. Look for Upgrade table and modify there manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Upgrade table to detect packages that do not have an `UpgradeCode` so the built-in upgrade logic has been rendered useless. You could create a minor upgrade to install over the existing MSI, and I *think* the minor upgrade could contain an upgrade code to get things back on track. I'm not 100% because I haven't shipped an MSI without an `UpgradeCode`. The WiX Toolset warns you never to do that... for this very reason.